# How to execute PreparedStatement with IN clause?

Tags: java, sql, spring, mariadb

The question is *NOT* answered in the linked one!

I want to feed an `IN` claubse with a `List` or `Set` of `Strings`:

```
private static final ItemPreparedStatementSetter<MyItem> PREPARED_SETTER = (item, ps) -> {
    ps.setObject(1, item.mylist); //being a List<String> or Set<String>
};

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM mytable where somefield IN (?)");
PREPARED_SETTER.setValues(item, ps);
ps.addBatch();
ps.executeBatch();
```

Result:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid utf8 character string: 'ACED00'
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readErrorPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1683)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1545)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1508)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AsyncMultiRead.call(AsyncMultiRead.java:132)
    ... 5 more
```

The invalid `AC ED 00` hint means there is a problem with the object (item.mylist) during serialization.

Question: how can I properly pass a `List` or `Set` into the `IN` clause?

Comment: I suggest you indicate why you can't use the answer from the linked question if you want this re-opened.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN because the linked question is about (and shows a solution for) `JdbcTemplate`, which is a totally different class than `PreparedStatement` in my question. Even if the answer to my question would be "*it's not possible with PreparedStatement*", even then this would be a valid answer, and in no case a duplicate.

Comment: The non-spring answer is you have to construct the query with a ? placeholder for  each member of the set that IN uses. You can’t directly pass in a collection.